# Grails plugin: static resource

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I've a controller `myController` and statis HTML `myHtml.html` inside my grails plugin named `myPlugin`.
Plugin is used inside my project named `myProject`. 
I can access the controller using this

`http://localhost:8080/myProject/myController`

However, I can't access statis HTML neither using

`http://localhost:8080/myProject/myHtml.html` 
nor 
`http://localhost:8080/myProject/static/plugins/myPlugin/myHtml.html`
not
`http://localhost:8080/myProject/static/plugins/myPlugin-${plugin-version}/myHtml.html`
Is that possible to access statis HTML inside plugin?

Comment: shouldn't that be `static` instead of `statis` ? check your urls again or correct the typo if it is a typo

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed your plugin, you should search for the html in a folder named "views" located in myProject\target\work\plugins\myPlugin\grails-app

That's where your html should be.

Comment: how to access it through web?